# Fixing Spline curves so as to not overlap with themselves - (Diagrams)

Tags: plotting, graphics, splines

**Statement of the problem:**

Conceptually, what I'm trying to achieve is pretty simple. I have some code that generates a set of diagrams from a list of sets of points using BSplineCurve. Certain conditions cause some of these diagrams to come out differently from what I need. With SplineDegree -> 1 the images look like:

[image: Spline Degree 1]

and with SplineDegree -> 3 the images become:

[image: Spline Degree 3]

The problematic cases are images a7, a8 and a9, which I need to look like:

[image: Correct Images]

The general rule is that I need closed smooth curves through the specified points, but the curve must not lie on top of itself when the points all lie on a straight line (I also need the curves to pass directly through the points, but this is another issue that is probably fairly easily solved - I've tried clamping without much success so far).

I have tried to solve this problem by implementing clunky IF statements that add additional guide points, but in addition to the fact that I struggle to make it work, it's very undesirable, because I need this to generalize to more complicated diagrams. For example, here is a preview of the higher dimensional case (the full list is very long):

[image: Higher Dimension Sample]

The last five images are problematic and should look like

[image: Correct Higher Dimension Sample]

I have also considered using Graph to try and do this, but I'm not really sure where to start.

**Code:**

I can't provide the full code, because the process of generating the list of points is exceptionally long. Here is the section that is relevant:

```
Clear[\[Delta]ToBirdTrack1];
Options[\[Delta]ToBirdTrack1] = {Background -> White, Trace -> Tr, 
   Scale -> 1};
\[Delta]ToBirdTrack1[expr_, A_: a, B_: b, 
   options___Rule] := \[Delta]ToBirdTrack1[expr, A, B, options] = 
   Module[{l, s, aa, bb, h, res, res1, hsep, vsep, samesep, bgcolor, 
 trace, scale, split},

(* options *)
bgcolor = Background /. {options} /. Options[\[Delta]ToBirdTrack1];
trace = Trace /. {options} /. Options[\[Delta]ToBirdTrack1];
scale = Scale /. {options} /. Options[\[Delta]ToBirdTrack1];

hsep = 5;
vsep = 2;
samesep = hsep/6;
l = (expr // 
     Cases[#, Subscript[A,  i], Infinity, Heads -> True] & // 
    Union // Length);
h = l*vsep;

(*line 1*)
res = (expr /. 
      Tr[aa__] :> m[Line[(*Append[*)aa(*,First[aa]]*)]] //. 
     m[aa__] m[bb__] -> m[aa, bb]) /. UP -> Sequence /. 
  Subscript[t, i_] -> i;

(*line 2*)
res = res // (# /. m[aa__] :> (m[aa] /. a_Line :> pos /@ a)) &;

(*line 3*)
res // (# /. 
     Line[aa__] :> 
      BSplineCurve[{aa}, SplineClosed -> True]) & // (# /. 
    m[aa__] :> Graphics[{aa}]) &
];

ExplicitList[NgI[2]] // 
  Sum[Subscript[\[Alpha], i] #[[i]], {i, 
 Length[#]}] & // \[Delta]ToBirdTrack1[#] &
```

I can't provide the data being put into this code, again because of length, but I can however show what it looks like. At "line 1" res is being shaped into this list:

[image: Algebraic List]

At "line 2" it is shaped into this list:

[image: Line object list of coordinates]

And at "line 3" the "aa's" that are being considered by the Spline Curve plotting look like this:

[image: Coordinates]

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, with the most general solution being the goal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way with `Interpolation`.  It passes through the points as the OP desires. It specifies the velocity (derivative) through the points by bisecting the exterior angle of the polygon; if the path turns back on itself, it specifies a velocity at a right angle (to the "left" of the direction of approach to the vertex) to the edge.  The `weights` multiply the velocities; it can be a single scalar or a list of scalars, one for each vertex.   There are probably shortcomings with more complicated diagrams but it works pretty well on the ones I tested.

```
Clear[diag, intPts];
intPts[list_, weights_: 1] := 
  With[{dl = 
     weights (Through[{Cos, Sin}[
           If[Total[#] == {0, 0}, ArcTan @@ Cross@First@#, 
            ArcTan @@ Total[#]]]] & /@ (Normalize /@ # &) /@ 
         Differences /@ Partition[list, 3, 1, 2])},
   Transpose@{
     List /@ Rescale[Range[1 + Length@list]],
     Append[#, First@#] &@list,
     Append[#, First@#] &@dl}
   ];
diag[pts_] := Interpolation /@ intPts /@ pts;
diag[pts_, wts_List] := Interpolation /@ MapThread[intPts, {pts, wts}];
diag[pts_, wts_] := Interpolation /@ (intPts[#, wts] &) /@ pts;
```

Examples

Since copyable coordinates weren't provided, I made up my own.  These are like the last three of the first set of the OP's examples.

```
a7 = {{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}, {{2, 0}, {0, 1}}};
a8 = {{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {2, 1}}};
a9 = {{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{2, 0}, {2, 1}}};
GraphicsRow[
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Through[diag[#][t]], {t, 0, 1}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick,
    Prolog -> {EdgeForm @ Directive[Dashed, Thickness[Small], Red], 
      Opacity[0], Polygon /@ #},
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point /@ #}] & /@ {a7, a8, a9}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The last three figures of the second set of examples:

```
d3 = {{{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 0}, {2, 2}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}}};
d4 = {{{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}}};
d5 = {{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 1}, {2, 1}}};
GraphicsRow[
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate @ Through[diag[#, 5][t]], {t, 0, 1}, 
    Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick,
    Prolog -> {EdgeForm @ Directive[Dashed, Thickness[Small], Red], 
      Opacity[0], Polygon /@ #},
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point /@ #}] & /@ {d4, d5, d6}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]